# How to pause ZXing reading untill the user close the alert message in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, zxing

I am implementing ZXing barcode reader , so when the user scan the wrong bar code , an alert messsage pops up ehich says that was the wrong barcode. The problem is that , the scaner keeps scanning behind the alert message and keeps poping up the same alert. I want the scanner to pause untill the user close the alert message. thats my code , and by the way , zxing.IsAnalyzing = false; is not working

```
 zxing = new ZXingScannerView
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                AutomationId = "zxingScannerView",
            };


            zxing.OnScanResult += (result) =>
            {

                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    if (!result.Text.Equals(auftrag.code))
                        {
                        zxing.IsAnalyzing = false;
                            await DisplayAlert("Barcode nicht gefunden.", "Der Barcode gehört nicht zu dem gewählten Auftrag.", "OK");

                        }
                        else

                        await Navigation.PushAsync(new AuftragDescription(auftrag));
                        }
                });
            };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve your problem by adding the bool field called _isScanning and set it to true. And when `Zxing`  "triggers" the `OnScanResult` it will check if `_isScanning` is true, it will set scanning and analyzing to false, and it will do your work check code or other things that you want, after it is done it will set back Analyzing and Scanning to true and you will continue to scan other barcodes.

All the time Zxing will be scanning but it will not interrupt you when you are showing the `DisplyAlert`.

Hope that this is not confusing, this is the simplest way to accomplish your needs.

Here is the code:

```
// add this bool field in your class
private bool _isScanning = true;
// ... 
// your other code...
// ... 

zxing = new ZXingScannerView {
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    AutomationId = "zxingScannerView",
};


zxing.OnScanResult += (result) => {

    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async() => {

        if (_isScanning) {
            _isScanning = false;
            zxing.IsAnalyzing = false;

            if (!result.Text.Equals(auftrag.code)) { 
                await DisplayAlert("Barcode nicht gefunden.", "Der Barcode gehört nicht zu dem gewählten Auftrag.", "OK");

            } else

                  await Navigation.PushAsync(new AuftragDescription(auftrag));
            }

            zxing.IsAnalyzing = true;
            _isScanning = true;
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: I am glad that it worked for you, also don't forget to make up vote for the answer if you think that I deserve it. Best regards!

Comment: It is ok, best regards! Good luck with coding! :D